# Не отображает css django

Tags: python, django

У меня не подключаеться файл css, тоесть он есть но браузер его не использует и не видит когда я в url пишу https://127.0.0.1/static/ и путь к css файлу. Django 4.1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coustard:900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="{% static 'warsaw/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
```

это начало html файла

ошибка в браузере: because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: а вы собирали статику?

Comment: нет, но когда собрал тоже ничего не поменялось

Comment: теперь нужно смотреть по какому маршруту он ищет статику и по какому она лежит